# Python-ggplot: Adding moving average to plot

Tags: python, statistics, moving-average, python-ggplot, plotnine

```
p = ggplot(cases, aes(x="Specimen date", y="Daily lab-confirmed cases", group = 1)) + geom_point() + geom_line() + labs(title = "Daily COVID-19 Cases")
p.save(filename = date_today, height=5, width=15, units = 'in', dpi=1000)
```

This is my current code to plot a graph from a DataFrame containing COVID-19 cases in England, which is then saved. I'm trying to add a trend line that is similar to the Worldometer graphs (as shown below).

I cannot post images yet, so I will provide the example [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uhJg.png).

[This is what my graph currently looks like.](https://i.imgur.com/VTlhUbL.png)

I am trying to achieve the **'3-day moving average'** and the **'7-day moving average'**.

Answer (score 1):

See [stat_smooth](https://plotnine.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generated/plotnine.stats.stat_smooth.html#plotnine.stats.stat_smooth), you can smooth using a moving average.

For example you may end up adding code like

```py
+ stat_smooth(method='mavg', method_args={'window': 3}, color='cyan')
+ stat_smooth(method='mavg', method_args={'window': 7}, color='blue')
```

But this will not give you a legend, because the moving average is not a variable (with a corresponding value) in the dataframe, i.e. given what you want to plot the data is not tidy. So if you want a legend you will have to compute the moving average, create a [tidy dataframe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tidy_data) and plot the computed averages that are in tidy form.

How? Use [pandas.melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) e.g.

```py
# Compute moving averages
cases['mavg_3'] = cases['Daily lab-confirmed cases'].rolling(window=3).mean()
cases['mavg_7'] = cases['Daily lab-confirmed cases'].rolling(window=7).mean()

# Convert data Long/tidy format
cases_long = cases.melt(
    id_vars=['Specimen date', 'Daily lab-confirmed cases'],
    value_vars=['mavg_3', 'mavg_7'],
    var_name='mavg_type',
    value_name='mavg_value'
)

# Plot tidy data
(ggplot(cases_long, aes(x="Specimen date", y="Daily lab-confirmed cases"))
 + geom_point()
 + geom_line(aes(y='mavg_value', color='mavg_type'), na_rm=True)
)
```

Comment: I'll have to do some research into this as I'm still fairly new to dataframes and such. However, you've pointed me in the right direction so thank you very much!